# Need a simple reg ex for url checking

Tags: regex

I am looking for it about 2 hours, but can not find what I need.

what I need is very simple:

1. allow: google.com, http://google.com, https://google.com
2. disallow spaces "goo gle.com"
3. with a valid domain: I mean it should have a dot "." + any domain (.com, .net etc.)
4. and allow anything after that: "googl.com/dsfsdf/sdfs/blablahblah/" without spaces

thanks

Edit:
Thanks all, I had to write it myself.

```
    if (!/^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?([a-z0-9_\.-]+)\.{1}([a-z0-9_\/\?\=\-\%-]+)$/.test(uri) 
|| /([\._\/\?\=\-\%-])\1/.test(uri)) {                                                     
    }
```

ps: I am noob in regexs.

Comment: Can you show your last attempted regex!

Comment: ^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+.*)$ This allows spaces in domain name "google.c om"

Comment: This is an excellent example of a question that should have been searched.  Next time you have a programming problem, ask yourself "I wonder if anyone else has had to solve this problem before," and if the answer is "Yes", then do a search for it.

Comment: @AndyLester I dont understand you.

Comment: The problem that you were facing, "How do I validate a URL", is a very common one.  If you think about it, you'll probably realize that you are not the first person to be faced with this problem to solve.  So, if you have a very common problem to be solved, the very first thing you should do is search for the problem, such as "how can I validate a URL?", and then use the answer that you find, instead of asking a question that has already been answered a thousand times.

Answer (score 1):

- www.google.com
- http://www.google.com
- mailto:somebody@google.com
- somebody@google.com
- www.url-with-querystring.com/?url=has-querystring

The **REGEX** below matches all the above cases

```
((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)
```

[**REGEX Explanation can be found here**](http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without-the)

[**Working Example**](http://rubular.com/r/ubZM1E6vol)

Answer (score 0):

Something that's working for me on a production product (haven't received any complaints yet):

```
((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)?[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])
```

Comment: your regex matches ww.google.com too, check here http://rubular.com/r/WTNDNolyLb

Comment: well, ww.google.com is a valid url (even if you try to put it in a browser you'll get to google.com) - that's because "ww" could be a sub-domain

Comment: @developer82 this allows spaces

Comment: @developer82 what about ww.gmail.com then??

Comment: @jack the space is resulted in 2 different addresses. what you could do is add a limit to the domain extension and limit it. but it doesn't make it less valid.

Comment: @Amarnath ww.gmail.com - is still a valid domain name (where "ww" could be the sub-domain as I mentioned earlier). RegEx checks that a certine string matches - not that the domain actually alive and functioning - the face that "ww.gmail.com" results in "opps" doesn't make it an invalid domain.